# Adobe Flash upgrade

Tags: flash

I upgraded my adobe flas and now everything is messed up.  Computer keeps telling me it is not installed, need to upgrade or enable.  All is done by still errors, then on some programs it gives the gray box and hestitates and then loads.  What can I do to fix.  Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall it completely and reinstall.